# Sbt not doing a full compile after being cloned?

Tags: git, scala, sbt

I tried to clone a scala project to a new server, and this worked the first time, however when I tried to update a few src files and do a push, then pull compile and run on the new server I had issues with sbt not having detected the changes in the file, but rather running the first version of the project I cloned on the server.

I deleted the project from the server, added /target and /project to the .gitignore, then tried re-cloning the project to the server, but when I compiled and ran it still ran the first version of the project. I also tried running `sbt clean` and then compiling and running again, but I had the same result.

When ever I compile it takes less than a second (except when I do a clean first, then it reloads the dependencies, then takes a second to compile), this makes me think sbt isn't doing a full re compile.

I am using sbt version 0.13.8 and scala version 2.11.6.

Any ideas what could solve this issue?

Comment: can you check in settings of your ide if you have enabled rebuild project on dependency change?

Comment: I use atom text editor then run sbt from the command line @Archana

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the `.gitignore` file I use with my Play / SBT projects. It's probably overkill, but I've never encountered a problem with SBT not picking up changes (even while it's running in the console!)

```
logs
dist
project/project
project/target
target
tmp
.history
/.idea
/*.iml
/out
/.idea_modules
/.classpath
/.project
/RUNNING_PID
/.settings
.DS_Store
**/.DS_Store
```

Comment: This worked. I already had project/project and project/target in the git ignore. I'm kind of curious which one of those made it work. Thanks!